# How can I create a list comprehension out of this deeply-nested 'for' loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

```
for role in self.collections[server.id][user.id]:
    for requested_set in self.roles[server.id]['sets']:
        if role in self.roles[server.id]['sets'][requested_set]['roles']:
            if requested_set not in requested_sets:
                requested_sets[requested_set] = []
            requested_sets[requested_set].append(role)
```

I tried to do this in steps.

Line 1 can be written as `[x for x in self.collections[server.id][user.id]]`.

Line 2 can be written as `[x for x in self.roles[server.id]['sets']]`.

Line 3 is where I get confused, as it incorporates line 1.

I started attempting as: `[x for x in (x for x in self.collections[server.id][user.id]) if x in self.roles[server.id]['sets'][requested_set]['roles']]`

However I see that I will need to incorporate a new variable to represent the absent `requested_set` variable. Is there a way I can put this all in one line?

Comment: I think it will be hard to read, and very long (I believe that there is a PEP8 for the maximum length of a line on a code).

Comment: Is there a reason for you to want this list comprehension? Cause code won't get any easier to read. Also, can't do `requested_sets[requested_set] = []` assigning in list comprehensions

Comment: Why would this be a list comprehension anyhow? That is for building lists, here you want to build a list as a value that is stored in `__setitem__` of an object (either a custom class or dictionary) based upon the value of one of your iterations.

Answer (score 1):

Putting all of this code into one line would be very inadvisable. Although I personally like list comprehensions, some people find them complicated. If this code has a possibility of being edited later, it would be better not write this on one line for maintenance purposes. The true cost of code is maintenance. AND, with my current knowledge, it is impossible to get that requested_set variable before its declaration. The code is simply too convoluted for it to be on one line.

However, it is not my place to tell you how to write your code. Because of the requested-set variable, it is impossible to put this all on one line, but it is possible in two lines:

```py
for requested_set in self.roles[server.id]['sets']:
    requested_sets[requested_set] = [role for role in self.collections[server.id][user.id] if role in self.roles[server.id]['sets'][requested_set]['roles']]
```